# How to Replace Misplaced OS Files

Tags: macbook-pro, snow-leopard

My Mom accidentally moved some system files on her Macbook Pro and did something so they can't be restored back to where they were and now some apps aren't working anymore. Is there a way to repair the installation of Mac OS or a way to figure out where these files should go? She doesn't have Time Machine set up by the way so that isn't an option.

Here is the list of files that she moved:

```
ATASMARTLib.h
Conversion.h
glut.h
IOAccelSurfaceConnect.h
IOCDTypes.h
IOFDiskPartitionScheme.h
IOFireWireLib.h
IOGraphicsInterface.h
IOGraphicsInterfaceTypes.h
IOGraphicsTypes.h
IOMacOSVideo.h
LogicAUProperties.h
USB 14-18-03 2.h
USB 14-18-03 3.h
USB 14-18-03 4.h
USB 14-18-03.h
USB.h
vDSP 14-17-08 2.h
vDSP 14-17-08.h
vDSP.h
```

Comment: Hm, those are all .h files, which are most likely header files. You might have a hard time compiling some stuff, but I can't imagine how that would break existing binaries

Comment: Completely agree with Kyle and Diago, non essential stuff, here. Do you have a list of the misbehaving applications? And are you sure there wasn't something else removed (you can do a lot of things wrong before finding and deleting those files)

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using?

Comment: @Justwes The tags say SL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

Simply take the original installation disc that came with the Mac and re-install OSX, afterwards just do a system update to bring it up to the latest version.

When OSX is installed over an existing installation, all settings and applications are preserved, and this should resolve all issue with the OS.

However, as @Kyle pointed out in the comments, the files moved are only header files used for compiling, and should not be affecting the working OS, and since the actual OS files are not available via the Finder, highly unlikely that she copied actual system files, unless she used Terminal.

If the applications still don't work after doing this, then those specific applications needs to be re-installed individually. The above procedure will work for all applications supplied by Apple as part of the OS.

Comment: Also, don't make mom an administrator. ;-) Hopefully, then she won't be able to do these sorts of things. You can always use iChat Screen Sharing to fix her problems or update her OS.